# Is there a way to schedule mails depending on whether or not a contact has opened a previous email?

Tags: scheduled-reminders

We are planning to take a lead capture action where we want to take two automated actions by email:

(1) Send an email the day after the contact is created in the CRM. This is possible through the Schedule Reminders tool.

(2) Send an email one week after the contact is created in the CRM only for those contacts who have not opened the first mail.

Is there any mechanism or functionality that will allow this second action to be performed?

Answer (score 3):

I've investigated this before.  The answer is "no, not without an extension", but we decided that email open rates were never reliable (because most email clients don't download the images by default).  It can give you an aggregate sense of engagement but isn't accurate down to the individual level.

Comment: Interesting reflection. It would only make sense to take such an action, assuming in advance that the email will be finally sent to people who have actually opened the email and that the system has not been able to register it. When you refer to most email clients, which of them do you mean? I understand that for example gmail, would not be the case, it download the images by default.

Comment: Every major mail client blocks images by default except GMail, Outlook.com (but Outlook 365 does block), and Apple Mail on iOS.  Older clients may also show by default - e.g. Outlook 2003 and earlier.

Comment: See also docs explanation at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/reports-and-analysis/#delivery-summary "How Open Tracking works"